# Bind to selected rows in GridControl

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, devexpress, gridcontrol

I would like to get a list of the objects selected in GridControl (DevExpress)

Would you know how I could do so?

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do this.

**Way 1**

If having DevExpress 15.5 (which I don't), simply use the `SelectedItem` property: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_SelectedItemstopic

**Way 2**

Create a behavior to hook the TableView inside the GridControl if you have:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">           
     <dxg:GridControl.View>
          <Controls:TableView >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <view:CollectionObserverBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCars}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          </Controls:TableView>
```

Behavior details in the good article here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22871.wpfmvvm-binding-to-read-only-properties-using-behaviors.aspx